# Find number combination in every row in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have ten column and multiple rows in one Excel sheet with numbers in it. How could I let VBA find all the combination in every row and add the number for all rows. 
For example, there is A2:100 and D2:7; C9:7 and F9:100 then it will output a format like 100+7:2

Comment: Can you please provide some more detail? Some sample data, inputs and expected output, would be great. It's hard to understand what you're looking for.  Why isn't it like, `100:2+7:2`?

Answer (score 0):

These steps should help get started.  Unless you are talking about every possible combination of the number, which is a far more complex topic.  You should try to write something and then edit your question to include your code.

- Loop the columns `For i = 1 to 10`
- Range(Cells(1, i),Cells(10,i)).Address(False,False) : e.g. A1:A10
- WorkSheetFunction.Sum(Range(Cells(1, i),Cells(10,i)).Address(False,False)): 100